# Rewrite If-else block using For loop

Tags: oracle, if-statement, for-loop, plsql

How can I write the following If-else block using for loop:

```
    BEGIN
        IF :new.plan_id = 1 THEN
          SELECT PLAN_MAX_START_HH24 INTO NEW_PLAN_MAX_START_HH24 FROM screening_plan WHERE plan_id = 1; 
          SELECT PLAN_MIN_START_HH24 INTO NEW_PLAN_MIN_START_HH24 FROM screening_plan WHERE plan_id = 1;
        ELSIF :new.plan_id = 2 THEN
          SELECT PLAN_MAX_START_HH24 INTO NEW_PLAN_MAX_START_HH24 FROM screening_plan WHERE plan_id = 2; 
          SELECT PLAN_MIN_START_HH24 INTO NEW_PLAN_MIN_START_HH24 FROM screening_plan WHERE plan_id = 2;
        ELSIF :new.plan_id = 3 THEN
          SELECT PLAN_MAX_START_HH24 INTO NEW_PLAN_MAX_START_HH24 FROM screening_plan WHERE plan_id = 3; 
          SELECT PLAN_MIN_START_HH24 INTO NEW_PLAN_MIN_START_HH24 FROM screening_plan WHERE plan_id = 3;
        ELSIF :new.plan_id = 4 THEN
          SELECT PLAN_MAX_START_HH24 INTO NEW_PLAN_MAX_START_HH24 FROM screening_plan WHERE plan_id = 4; 
          SELECT PLAN_MIN_START_HH24 INTO NEW_PLAN_MIN_START_HH24 FROM screening_plan WHERE plan_id = 4;
        END IF;
     END;
```

For some `plan_id` with values `1,2,3,4` , I have to select the `plan_max_start_hh24` and `plan_min_start_hh24`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think you need a FOR LOOP? I'm assuming that plan_id is a unique number (ie. each of the above queries returns at most 1 row).

Also, why do you do two selects? You can return multiple columns into their corresponding variables in one select statement.

I think you're probably wanting something like:

```
  if :new.plan_id in (1, 2, 3, 4) then
    select plan_max_start_hh24, plan_min_start_hh24
    into   new_plan_max_start_hh24, new_plan_min_start_hh24
    from   screening_plan
    where  plan_id = :new.plan_id;
  end if;
```

Don't forget to include an exception block to take into account the case where the above query doesn't return a row (and, in the case where plan_id is not a unique column, where it returns multiple rows).